# calling sqlite frequently in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

New to vb.net!
Using MS Visual Studio 2017 (Visual Basic)

Developing an app that get data (email addresses) from SQLite database and loads into an string, which then opens and Outlook (new message window) with the email addresses pre-filled.

The issue is that when I click the create new message button the first time it works but when I do it the second time the app hangs and there are no errors or any feedback from Visual Studio.

```
    Function GetAddresses(table As String)
    Dim Path As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\"
    Dim dataBase As String = "test.db"
    Dim cs As String = Path & dataBase
    Dim myConnection As New SQLiteConnection()
    Dim cadeomSQL As String = "Data Source=" & cs & ";"
    Dim resultString As String = ""

    myConnection.ConnectionString = cadeomSQL
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM " + table + ";"
    Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sSQL, myConnection)

        Dim rdr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        Using rdr
            While (rdr.Read())
                'MsgBox(rdr.GetInt32(0).ToString & " - " & rdr.GetString(1))
                resultString &= rdr.GetInt32(0).ToString & " - " & rdr.GetString(1)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    myConnection.Close()
    myConnection = Nothing
    Return resultString
End Function
```

And here is the calling method:

```
    Sub CreateEmail()
    Dim mapi As New My.MAPI
    Dim EmailAddresses As String = ""


    'get email addresses
    'based on checkboxes ticked
    For Each c As Control In GroupBox2.Controls
        If c.GetType Is GetType(CheckBox) Then
            Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(c, CheckBox)
            If cb.Checked Then
                MsgBox(cb.Text & " is checked")
                EmailAddresses &= GetAddresses(cb.Text)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox(EmailAddresses)


    'Attach files
    For Each rowView As DataRowView In ListBox1.Items
        Dim value As String = rowView("Value")
        'MsgBox(value)
        mapi.AddAttachment(value)
    Next


    mapi.AddRecipientTo(EmailAddresses)
    mapi.SendMailPopup("Subject", "body text")

    EmailAddresses = Nothing
    mapi = Nothing
End Sub
```

So I am not sure what is causing the app to hang the second time I press the create new message button.

[Screen shot of email form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C03v6.png)

Comment: Have you debugged your code?  I'll wager not.  A "hang" is either an infinite loop or a method that doesn't return.  If you had debugged, you'd be able to tell us which and where.  You should debug your code now.  If you still can't solve the issue for yourself, post back with all the relevant information.  If you don't know how to debug, learn how [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: thanks...forgot I had 'release' on and not 'debug'. So now it shows System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'unable to open database file'
the second time around! Doesn't myConnection.Close() close it?

Comment: You should create your connection object with a `Using` statement as you are doing for your command and data reader objects. That would ensure that the connection is closed even if an exception is thrown. I doubt that that is your issue though.

Comment: My guess is that the issue is that you're connection string is wrong.  Have you looked at the connection string when the exception is thrown? If the exception says that there's a connection issue, that should be one of the first things you do when you debug. You are using the current directory to build your connection string and that can change over the course of a session, so it's not something you should be doing for a specific file in a specific location.

Comment: code = CantOpen (14), message = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x800007FF): unable to open database file
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, String vfsName, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
   at Zappa.Form1.GetAddresses(String table) in C:\Users\zz\source\repos\WindowsApp2\WindowsApp2\Form1.vb:line 164

Comment: Please don't put anything very brief code or messages in comments.  The error message you're getting belongs in the question anyway, not a comment.  ALL the information relevant to the question should be in the question. That stack trace still doesn't indicate that you've actually looked at the connection string in sue at the time either.

Comment: sorry about that. As it turns you're right working directory changes to c:\program files\microsoft office.... So that I means I need to use something else instead of Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() If you can post that as an answer I'll accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to get the database folder path, I suspect that the file is in the same folder as the EXE.  The current directory is usually the program folder by default but it may not be and it can change over the course of a session, so it's best avoided unless you specifically want the current directory wherever it may be.

In a WinForms project, you can get the path of the program folder using `Application.StartupPath`, so I'd suggest that you replace this:

```
Dim Path As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\"
Dim dataBase As String = "test.db"
Dim cs As String = Path & database
```

with this:

```
Dim cs = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "test.db")
```